# dynamic attribute in JSP/JS

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

i am trying to create a form in JSP , which has 2 fields JOB band and Sub job band. based on the input of job band(selected by user) i would like to run a query on my database and fetch the sub job bands available for that particular job band and display it as a drop down menu on the web page.

i have tried using js(javascript) and using that i am able to dynamically display buttons on my webpage but am not sure how can i use it to fetch value from database and display on the page.

any help on this would be very helpful. please suggest any other way to solve the above problem

Answer (score 0):

you have to use Ajax technology for reload second select field. I recommend you jQuery javascript library. But, if you want you can write you own javascript for get data by ajax. I have code example here http://bit.ly/wv8jB6